# Can someone help me with an analysis excercise?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to prove that the series $\sum_{n≥1}\frac{x^n}{1 - x^n}$ converges uniformly in each compact set $K  \subset  \ ]-1,1[$ and absolutly in $]-1,1[$ but not converges uniformly in $]-1,1[$. Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on what the sequence $x_n$ is... Do you have any information on this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers. Besides, did you type $x_n$ for $x^{n}$?

Comment: Sorry, is not a sequence, is $x^n$

Comment: Hint: Show $|u_n(x)|\le 2k^n$ for $n\ge n_0=\frac{\ln(2)}{|\ln(k)|}$ for $x\in K=[0,k]$. so you have normal convergence of the series on compact $K$.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, studying the absolute convergence is equivalent to studying the convergence of the series. You can use the Radio test for $|f_n(x)| = |\frac{x^n}{1 - x^{n}}|$, you will get that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|f_{n+1}|}{|f_{n}|} < 1$ and the series converge absolutely in $]-1,1[$.

For converges uniformly in each compact set $K \subset]−1,1[$, you can try to use the Weierstrass M-test, for example, $|x|$ it will have a maximum in $K$ (since it is compact), then be that value, for example, $\rho$, $K \subset]−1,1[, \rho \in \mathbb{R}, 0 \le \rho < 1, K \subset [-\rho, \rho]$. You can bound $\frac{x^n}{1 - x^{n}} \le \frac{\rho^n}{1 - \rho^{n}}$ and the proving that $\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{\rho^n}{1 - \rho^n}$ converge (you can use the Radio test again) you will have the uniform convergence.

Finally, to prove that it does not converge on] -1,1 [you can suppose that the series would be Cauchy if it were true, but the truth is that not even the general term converges to $0$.